# Sitecore Search: how to query by Id using the indexer on the SearchResultItem

Tags: content-search

I'm trying to do this:

`queryable.Where(i => i["_template"] == templateId);`

Where `templateId` is a Guid string, but it doesn't work. However, this *does* work:

`queryable.Where(i => i["_templatename"] == templatename);`

What do I need to do in order to filter by ID?

P.S. I realise I can use the typed template ID property, but I need the field name to be dynamic.

Comment: Could you try to execute your query in Luke? Link to application http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Comment: Also _template field in index stores value like c6576836910c4a3dba03c277dbd3b827

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably isn't working because the value stored inside `i["_template"]` is the parsed GUID value from the index.

Try using:

`Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper.NormalizeGuid(templateId)`

This will convert any GUID to the format which is stored inside the search index.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something mode along the lines of:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();

predicate = predicate.Where(i => i.TemplateId = templateId);

var results = queryable.Where(predicate);
```

There is more info on this here: 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/developing/developing%20with%20sitecore/search%20and%20item%20buckets/linq%20to%20sitecore

Comment: as per my question, I realise I can do this, but I need the property name to be dynamic. i.e. it's not just the template id I might want to search on, it might be a custom droptree field

Comment: Sorry David I missed what you meant by that. Looks like you have a solution.